# How to plot a rotated ellipse using `ParametricPlot`?

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions, coordinate-transformation, rotation

I'm plotting the *von Mises yield surface* using `CountourPlot` and `ParametricPlot`.

With `ContourPlot` I get this nice rotated ellipse:

```
ContourPlot[Sqrt[sig1^2 + sig2^2 - sig1 sig2] - 200 == 0, {sig1, -300, 300}, {sig2, -300, 300}]
```

[image]

Now i need to find the parametric equations to plot a rotated ellipse similar to the ellipse above, but this time using the function `ParametricPlot`.

I can plot an ellipse with parametric, but it's not rotated:

```
ParametricPlot[{200 Cos[theta], 100 Sin[theta]}, {theta, 0 , 2 Pi}]
```

**EDIT:**

If the real von Mises yield surface is ploted (using `ContourPlot`) and compared with the plot obtaned from `ParametricPlot`:

```
contourplot = 
  ContourPlot[
   Sqrt[sig1^2 + sig2^2 - sig1 sig2] - 200 == 0, {sig1, -300, 
    300}, {sig2, -300, 300}];
gamma = Pi/4;
a = 300;
b = a/2;
pmplot = ParametricPlot[{(a Cos[theta] Cos[gamma] - 
      b Sin[theta] Sin[gamma]), 
    a Cos[theta] Sin[gamma] + b Sin[theta] Cos[gamma]}, {theta, 0 , 
    2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red, Dashed}];
Show[contourplot, pmplot]
```

[image]

we can see that the plots are not the same.

**How can i find the values of `a` and `b` that make the ellipses the same?**

Comment: The question added in your edit is rather different from your original question.  Instead of asking multiple questions in one post, you should post a new question and (if appropriate) link back to this one for context.

Comment: @Michael Seifert I have posted a new question.

Comment: Here is the link: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/174766/how-to-find-the-parametric-equation-of-the-von-mises-yield-function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [`RotationTransform`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RotationTransform.html)  to find the equation of our rotated function

```
RotationTransform[α][{a Cos[θ], b Sin[θ]}]
```

> ```
>   {a Cos[α] Cos[θ] - b Sin[α] Sin[θ], a Cos[θ] Sin[α] + b Cos[α] Sin[θ]}
> ```

Now you can plot it as any other equation.

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[
  RotationTransform[α][
   {
    200 Cos[theta],
    100 Sin[theta]
    }
   ]
  , {theta, 0, 2 Pi}
  , PlotRange -> {{-300, 300}, {-300, 300}}
  ]
 , {α, -π, π}
 ]
```

[image]