# How to find the parametric equation of the von Mises yield function?

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions, coordinate-transformation, rotation, solidmechanics

The von Mises yield function is given by:

$ 
\Phi(\sigma_1,\sigma_2)=\sqrt{\sigma_{1}^{2} +\sigma_{2}^{2}-\sigma_{1} \sigma_{2}} - \sigma_y 
$

were $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ are the principal stresses and $\sigma_y$ is the yield stress. If $\Phi(\sigma_1, \sigma_2)=0$, $\sigma_y =200$ and using `ContourPlot`:

```
contourplot = ContourPlot[Sqrt[sig1^2 + sig2^2 - sig1 sig2] - 200 == 0, {sig1, -300, 
300}, {sig2, -300, 300}]
```

I have:

[image]

I need to find the parametric version of $\Phi(\sigma_1,\sigma_2)$, but I'm stuck.

Still now based on this question [How to plot a rotated ellipse using `ParametricPlot`?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/174707/how-to-plot-a-rotated-ellipse-using-parametricplot), I can plot a rotated parametrized ellipse (red and dashed line) obtained from this code:

```
        a = 300;
        b = a/2;
gamma = Pi/4;
        pmplot = ParametricPlot[{(a Cos[theta] Cos[gamma] - b Sin[theta] Sin[gamma]), a Cos[theta] Sin[gamma] + b Sin[theta] Cos[gamma]}, {theta, 0 ,2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red, Dashed}];
    Show[contourplot, pmplot]
```

[image]

The problem is to find the values of `a` and `b` to fit the parametric equation with the von Mises ellipse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ClearAll[a, b, gamma]
table = Sqrt[#^2 + #2^2 - # #2] - 200 & @@@
  Table[{(a Cos[theta] Cos[gamma] - b Sin[theta] Sin[gamma]), 
     a Cos[theta] Sin[gamma] + b Sin[theta] Cos[gamma]}, 
   {theta, 0, Pi, Pi/4}]; 

{a, b, gamma} = NArgMin[{Norm @ table,  0 <= gamma <= 2 Pi}, {a, b, gamma}]
```

> {282.843, -163.299, 0.785398}

```
pmplot = ParametricPlot[{(a Cos[theta] Cos[gamma] - b Sin[theta] Sin[gamma]), 
    a Cos[theta] Sin[gamma] + b Sin[theta] Cos[gamma]}, 
  {theta, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red, Dashed}];
Show[contourplot, pmplot]
```

[image]

Comment: great solution! Do you know if it's possible to obtain analytically these constants (a,b and gamma)?

Comment: @Diogo, for an exact solution, you can use `eqns = Thread[
   FullSimplify[
       Norm[Sqrt[#^2 + #2^2 - # #2] - 
           200 & @@@ {(a Cos[theta] Cos[gamma] - 
            b Sin[theta] Sin[gamma]), 
          a Cos[theta] Sin[gamma] + b Sin[theta] Cos[gamma]}], 
       Assumptions -> { a > 0, 
         theta == #, 0 <= gamma <= Pi}] & /@ {0, Pi/2, Pi} == 0];
Reduce[Join[eqns, { 0 <= gamma <= 2 Pi}], {a, b, gamma}, Reals]` .

Comment: thank you. The solutions i get from your code are: a=200sqrt[2], b=200Sqrt[2] and gamma=2 ArcTan[Sqrt[2]/(2 + Sqrt[2])]. Both a and gamma are compatible with your numerical solution, but b appears to be diferent. Do you know why?

Comment: Apparently the exact solution is: a=sigmay sqrt(2), b=sigmay sqrt(2/3) and gamma =-2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you need a parametric von Mises yield criterion equation for plane stresses.

Von Mises yield criterion:

$\sigma_{1}^{2} - \sigma_{1}\sigma_{2} + \sigma_{2}^{2} = \sigma_{y}^{2}$

were $\sigma_{1}$ and $\sigma_{2}$ are the principal stresses and $\sigma_{y}$ is the yield stress.

Parametric equations for von Mises yield criterion:

$\sigma_{1} = 2\sigma_{y}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\cos t + \sin t) = 2\sigma_{y}(\cos t - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \sin t) = \frac{4\sigma_{y} \sin{t}}{\sqrt{3}}$

$\sigma_{2} = 2\sigma_{y}(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\cos t + \sin t) = 2\sigma_{y}(\cos t + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \sin t) = \frac{4\sigma_{y} \sin{(t + \pi/3)}}{\sqrt{3}}$

where $t$ is the parameter, which ranges from $0$ to $2π$ radians.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/108139)